# Why the sql query do not execute?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

This code is what i have tried to process the query, either delete or insert do not have affect.

The id is correct and conn.php is correct .

I just copy the sql query to phpmyadmin to test and it works.

And i put a `echo "test";` between `try{}` it echo too.

Thank you

```
<?
include("../connection/conn.php");
session_start();

$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
// list out the pervious create list
//$id=$_GET['id'];

$id=3;
try{
$sql = 'INSERT INTO delete_list SELECT * FROM list WHERE ListID=?';
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute(array($id));
}
catch(PDOException $e)
    {
    die ($e->getMessage().'<a href="view.php"> Back</a>'); 
    }

try{
$sql = 'INSERT INTO delete_user_list SELECT * FROM user_list WHERE ListID=?';
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute(array($id));
}
catch(PDOException $e)
    {
    die ($e->getMessage().'<a href="view.php"> Back</a>'); 
    }

try{
$sql = 'INSERT INTO delete_require_attributes SELECT * FROM require_attributes WHERE ListID=?';
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute(array($id));
}
catch(PDOException $e)
    {
    die ($e->getMessage().'<a href="view.php"> Back</a>'); 
    }

try{
$sql = 'INSERT INTO delete_subscriber SELECT * FROM subscriber WHERE ListID=?';
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute(array($id));
$count=$stmt->rowCount();
}
catch(PDOException $e)
    {
    die ($e->getMessage().'<a href="view.php"> Back</a>'); 
    }

try{
$sql = 'INSERT INTO delete_list_sub SELECT * FROM list_sub WHERE ListID=?';
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute(array($id));
}
catch(PDOException $e)
    {
    die ($e->getMessage().'<a href="view.php"> Back</a>'); 
    }


    try{
$sql = 'DELETE FROM list WHERE ListID = ?';
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute(array($id));
}
catch(PDOException $e)
    {
    die ($e->getMessage().'<a href="view.php"> Back</a>'); 
    }

echo "The list has been deleted.".$count." subscribers has been removed. <a href='view.php'> Back</a>";

?>
```

i added

```
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

and error is

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'ListID' in 'where clause' Back
```

Comment: It's great that you're using PDO, but if you're not using parameterised queries, you're still leaving an enormous security gap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't work because in order for variables to be interpolated you need to use double quotes (") not single quotes. Single quotes makes it literally pass "$id" instead of the value.

But since you're using PDO you should be using prepared statements! Like this:

```
$sql = 'INSERT INTO delete_list SELECT * FROM list WHERE ListID=?'
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql)
$stmt->execute(array($id));
```

The value of `$id` replaces the `?`

EDIT: fixed the parameter

Comment: thx ,double quote is not the reason . I changed and it still not work

Answer (score 1):

using single quotes in php may be the problem:

```
$sql = 'INSERT INTO delete_user_list SELECT * FROM user_list WHERE ListID=$id';
```

here, $id won't be resolved by php interpreter because of single quote which is 'raw string'

if you want $id to be resolved, use " (double quote)

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO delete_user_list SELECT * FROM user_list WHERE ListID=$id";
```

or use parameterized statements (preferred & much safer)

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO delete_user_list SELECT * FROM user_list WHERE ListID=?";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute($id);
```

Comment: thx ,double quote is not the reason . I changed and it still not work

Comment: also Warning: PDOStatement::execute() expects parameter 1 to be array, integer given in C:\xampp\htdocs\fyp\list\delete.php on line 12 for parameterized statements, So i change to $stmt->execute(array($id));

Comment: @LeoChan - yes your right I forget that I have a wrapper that does the right thing with the parameters. They to need to be an array. Fixed my example to reflect.

Answer (score 0):

Which of the queries does not get executed? Can you check whether there is a connection at all (meaning are your credentials correct)?

Comment: Every query not works, the connection to db is correct, i just use another php to try to insert